# Using Python & Pip

Tags: linux, python, jenkins, pip

I am trying to configure Python & Python3 for a Linux Jenkins slave to use. I have been advised to use Pip for Python, and Pip3 for Python3 in terms of managing modules. I'm not sure how, but both Pip and Pip3 are pointing to my Python 3.6 installation. 
That may be a red herring, but I am trying to import a module 'SlackClient' and being told that the module can't be found, even though it also says it's already installed. See below for more detail:

```
$ python py.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SlackClient
ImportError: No module named SlackClient

$ python3 py.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SlackClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SlackClient'
```

Whenever I try to install the module:

```
$ pip install slackclient
Requirement already satisfied: slackclient in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp>3.5.2 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from slackclient) (3.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: aiodns>1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from slackclient) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna-ssl>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<5.0,>=4.0 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (4.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5; python_version < "3.7" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (3.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycares>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from aiodns>1.0->slackclient) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing; python_version < "3.7" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from aiodns>1.0->slackclient) (3.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from idna-ssl>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from pycares>=3.0.0->aiodns>1.0->slackclient) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi>=1.5.0->pycares>=3.0.0->aiodns>1.0->slackclient) (2.19)
```

My environments are set like this:

```
$ python --version
    Python 2.7.14
$ python3 --version
    Python 3.6.8
$ pip --version
    pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
$ pip3 --version
    pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

$ which pip
    /usr/local/bin/pip
$ which pip3
    /usr/local/bin/pip3
$ which python
    /usr/bin/python
$ which python3
    /usr/bin/python3
```

It seems odd that Python can't see the modules. The only thing I can think of is that it looks like both Pips are installing packages to Python 3.6, but then I don't understand why Python3 can't find the modules either.

Comment: Try `$ python -m pip --version` ; what does it print? `Requirement already satisfied: slackclient in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/...` indicates that slackclient (note: all lower case! That is not what you have tried to import!) is present/installed for python 3 only.

Comment: It returns `pip 19.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
`. I can check for 'SlackClient' and it also says that is installed.

Comment: How about changing the camelcaps `import SlackClient` into `import slackclient` (to make it match the filename)?

Comment: Same error unfortunately...

Comment: `https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient` @ Requirements, says as far as I can tell that you need to use an older version for python 2. You see the same version reported for python 2. I'd guess this is a problem: My first move here would be to remove all installed versions and "start from scratch". (Note: logic decision, not based on other facts).

Comment: I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling, but to no avail.